# Not able to write file in android internal storage

Tags: android

please give me an hand.

i'm trying to write something in a file text in Android internal storage.

i'm using the stream method like the following.
By the way, it does not write .

could you help me to solve?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    File f=new File("box");
    public void scrivi(String data)
    {try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        pw.write("");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e ){
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, ("Il FILE NON ESITE"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();

    }
    }

    public void read( String word)
    {try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String line="";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null);
        println(line);
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException n){Toast x = Toast.makeText(this, ("Il FILE NON SI PUO' LEGGERE"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        x.show();}
        catch(IOException w){{Toast q = Toast.makeText(this, ("c'e' un problema"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            q.show();}}
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
            Intent j = getIntent();
            String nome = j.getStringExtra("nome");
            lista.add(nome);
            scrivi(nome);








        if(nome!=null)

    {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, ("ciao " + " " + nome), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }}







    public void go(View v){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
    public void time(View c){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,ActivityPicker.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void pass(View p){
        EditText nome6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome6);
        String inviaDati = nome6.getText().toString();
        read(inviaDati);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops. Good catch. Misread the questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
File f=new File("box");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Will attempt to open and if necessary create a file in the current working directory **which is not writeable on Android**

If you replace `new fileOutputStream(f)` with `openFileOutput(f)` called within or on an instance of an Activity or other valid Context you will get a file in your app's internal storage as suggested by your title.

`openFileInput(f)` can be used on the reading side.  You can also obtain this location as a path with `getFilesDir()` should you want to use it explicitly.

Shine's recommendations of writing something non empty and using logging rather than Toasts for detail are also important.

I'd additionally suggest you explicitly close the output stream rather than waiting for that to happen when it is garbage collected some unpredictable time after the end of the method where it was contained.

Comment: good answer! I didn't think about openFileOutput(). I guess that best solution would be to pass a Context, as suggested

Comment: @Shine  as you could understand i'm a beginner  and , i confess, i have not clear the Context concept.Cuold you suggest me a link for explanations?  could you suggest me how could i modify the code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not using `data` inside `scrivi()` method. Try with this:

```
 public void scrivi(String data, Context ctx){
  try {
       FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput();
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
       pw.write(data);
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e ){
      Log.e("ERR", e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

As a side note, I don't recommend to use Toast in inner "business" methods, as it may not work as expected if called outside Activity context. To trace errors, just use Log.warn/info/debug